# What is this known in dart?

Tags: function, dart

Actually I am very much confused about this statement in dart and its (_) when does this required and what's difference with () ...What document should I read to make this concept clear
like

```
TextField(
          onSubmitted: (_) {
            onsubmit();
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

The onSubmitted callback function provides the submitted String in the text field as a value, so you can work with it and process it further in the function.

```
TextField(
  onSubmitted: (String value) { print("Submitted value: $value"); },
),
```

If you for whatever reason don't need this value, because you do not use it in the function, you can replace the `String value` with a `_`, so anyone who reads the code immediately knows that this value is not used.

You can't just leave it out like this:

```
TextField(
  onSubmitted: () { print("Doing something"); },
),
```

because you will get the error:

```
The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?'.
```

So you just assign the value to this variable called `_`, which you are never going to use.

```
TextField(
      onSubmitted: (_) { print("Doing something"); },
),
```

[Relevant section in the "Effective Dart" Guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#prefer-using-_-__-etc-for-unused-callback-parameters)